# Example use of TimeSpan.MinValue? Why would anyone use that in practice?

Tags: c#, .net, timespan

I was using TimeSpans and found about [TimeSpan.MinValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.minvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in MSDN. I was wondering why they include that directly in the class, or better yet: if there was a classic example of why/when you would want to use it. Of course it's good to *know* the value, but one can look that up.

I thought of stuff like subtracting other TimeSpans but it doesn't really make sense to me.

Any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: Two words: Code readability.

Comment: Why does it not make sense to you to subtract timespans?  Ten minutes minus seven minutes is three minutes; those are all time spans.

Comment: @EricLippert not subtracting timespans, but subtracting a timespan from minvalue.

Comment: You can't subtract a positive timespan from minvalue. It's already the smallest value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing that comes to mind:

```
static TimeSpan FindMax(params TimeSpan[] intervals) {
    if (intervals.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("intervals collection is empty");
    var max = TimeSpan.MinValue;
    foreach (var interval in intervals) {
        if (interval > max)
            max = interval;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: `var max = intervals[0]` works just as well as an initializer.

Answer (score 1):

`TimeSpan` is a `struct`, not a `class`. This means it cannot have a null value (without wrapping it in a [System.Nullable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)). Therefore, what value should it be given if you instantiate a variable as a `TimeSpan`?

The designer has opted for the minimum value possible, but rather than encode this as a magic value, they have exposed it as the `TimeSpan.MinValue` constant.

Comment: This answer is wrong. You have confused MinValue with Zero.

Comment: `struct` cannot be declared as `const`. [`TimeSpan.MinValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) is `static readonly`.

Comment: The value is not by choice, but by design. The value of this field is equivalent to Int64.MinValue(negative 9,223,372,036,854,775,808) ticks. And, that is the max(or should i say, minimum) you can store, without underflowing `int64`.

Answer (score 1):

One example I can give you is where it could be used as an alternative to a `Nullable` TimeSpan property in a class (`TimeSpan` is Nullable, by the way)

And you're displaying some text somewhere - that relies on something being "set" (or not).

Let's say a `string` that is showing how long something has been running.

Use a full property (with backing field) to achieve this:

Set the initial field's value to `TimeSpan.MinValue` which you can then use a public property to alter. Then, for the string you want to display, use your favourite PropertyChanged event handler (or other code) to update your view:

```
private TimeSpan _lengthOfTime = TimeSpan.MinValue;
public TimeSpan LengthOfTime
{
    get { return _lengthOfTime; }
    set
    {
        _lengthOfTime = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("LengthOfTimeString");
    }
}

public string LengthOfTimeString
{
    get
    {
        if (LengthOfTime == TimeSpan.MinValue)
        {
            return "The length of time has not been set.";
        }
        else
        {
            return LengthOfTime.ToString("YourFavouriteStringFormatHere");
        }
    }
}
```

When you then update your `LengthOfTime` property, it will call `OnPropertyChanged` (or whatever you use to update the UI) to `get` the `LengthOfTimeString` value, which is then re-calculated and displayed on your view.

This is only an example; and your scenario of what to use it for might be different.

I would suggest looking at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614(v=vs.100).aspx, which tells you about how to implement INotifyPropertyChanged; if you're thinking of using Bindings in WPF/XAML/WinRT (if you don't know how to already).

Comment: Though this usage is common, it's a bad practice. If you want to indicate that something is unset, make a *nullable timespan*, and set it to null.

Comment: I agree; where possible create a `Nullable` `TimeSpan` property. However, the original question was for an example of what a `TimeSpan.MinValue` could be used for.

Comment: I think bad practice is to use null for this, because you always risk "a billion-dollar mistake", only the exception would be different